# Why doesn't this bokeh scatter graph show anything?

Tags: python, scatter-plot, bokeh

I am trying to make a scatter graph using python, which shows league positions and rookie/veteran team information for a year by year basis. 
I want there to be columns of points, with one column per year, and one point per position, where the colour of the point depends on whether they are a rookie or a veteran.

I have this code, but it doesn't seem to show any data. Why?

```
from bokeh.charts import Scatter, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import Range1d
#from vdata.data import get_schools
from collections import OrderedDict

def get_data(years):
    schools = get_schools(['raw_data/2015-teams.yaml'], [2015])

    d = OrderedDict()
    d['rookie'] = []
    d['veteran'] = []

    for s in schools:
        for year in years:
            rookie = s.data[year]['rookie']
            league_position = s.data[year]['league']

            if rookie:
                d['rookie'].append((year, league_position))
            else:
                d['veteran'].append((year, league_position))
    return d

data = OrderedDict([('rookie', [(2015, 14), (2015, 26), (2015, 47), (2015, 41), (2015, 24), (2015, 45), (2015, 35), (2015, 46), (2015, 21), (2015, 47), (2015, 5), (2015, 31), (2015, 28), (2015, 30), (2015, 18)]), ('veteran', [(2015, 13), (2015, 27), (2015, 42), (2015, 18), (2015, 39), (2015, 34), (2015, 22), (2015, 2), (2015, 3), (2015, 43), (2015, 8), (2015, 40), (2015, 1), (2015, 29), (2015, 4), (2015, 18), (2015, 44), (2015, 7), (2015, 23), (2015, 16), (2015, 32), (2015, 6), (2015, 37), (2015, 25), (2015, 11), (2015, 38), (2015, 17), (2015, 12), (2015, 15)])])

def league_rookie(d):
    scatter = Scatter(d, title='League positions and rookie values', legend=True, ylabel='League Position', xlabel='Year', width=1000, height=600, y_range=Range1d(60, 0))
    output_file('visuals/html/league_rookie.html')
    show(scatter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #data = get_data([2015])
    league_rookie(data)
```

I feel this isn't a great way of using a Scatter plot, but I'm don't know how else to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted has example data with only a single x value. If you change your sample data so that just one point is for a different year (I changed the year of the first point to be 2014) then the data graphs fine using the code exactly as you posted it (as long as you create the save location).

It seems also that your get_data() function is returning data for only a single year which will cause the same problem.

If your desired graph is actually just a single vertical column of points, then perhaps you can have a third dummy series that uses a different year and then just hide the legend entry and set the viewing window to exclude the dummy data.

I'm guessing you want something nicer than that. If you provide a mock up of what you want the graph to actually look like, maybe using excel or something, you will get much better answers.

Comment: You were correct. My desired graph was a single vertical column of points (at least for the first year).